# npm doesn't work on an ARM embedded device

Tags: node.js, arm, npm

I installed Node.js on an embedded device running with a core Linux 3.0.

When I try to execute npm to install some modules, I get the follow issue :

```
DM-37x# npm

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/local/bin/npm:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:86:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I already tried to reinstall node.js but the bug is still here.

How can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing (or reinstalling) npmlog.

See https://www.npmjs.org/package/npmlog

Make sure you have a package.json file in the top level of your project directory (each project).

Use npm ls
and
npm update

to make sure the npmlog package is included.

Comment: The main problem is when I try to install npmlog or launch          nay command with npm, I get the same error.